# J2ME-Polish: platforms.xml example

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

has someone a working J2ME-Polish platforms.xml for the BlackBerry **6.0** (or for any other Java platform)? I have no idea, how that file should look like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install J2ME-Polish you have the option of including the external devices database which contains an up to date platforms.xml file with definitions for BlackBerry devices from version 4.0 to 6.0. The external devices database files are found in the J2ME-Polish installation folder.

Comment: Thanks, but does 2.1.4 include BlackBerry 6.0? 5.0 is the latest one in my installation. Anyway, it should be a simple modification of the platforms.xml.

Comment: Yes, 2.1.4 does include a platform definition for BlackBerry 6.0.